# Ruby Sequel, "insert ignore" returns undefined method?

Tags: ruby, database, sqlite, sequel

Trying to do a multi_insert (or insert, for that matter) with the Sequel gem, using "insert_ignore". I get an undefined method error.
The table

```
DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://database.db')

DB.create_table! :users do
        primary_key :id
        String :name, :default => nil, :unique => true
end

users = [{:name => 'bob'}, {:name => 'bob'}, {:name => 'mary'}]

DB[:users].insert_ignore.multi_insert(users)
```

this returns

```
undefined method "insert_ignore" for <#Sequel::SQLite::Dataset: "SELECT * FROM 'users'"> (NoMethodError)
```

what's wrong? Does SQLite3 not support insert_ignore statements?
confused!

Answer (score 2):

> Does SQLite3 not support insert_ignore statements? confused!

The Sequel docs for `Sequel::MySQL::DatasetMethods`, which are here:

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc-adapters/classes/Sequel/MySQL/DatasetMethods.html#method-i-insert_ignore

list the method insert_ignore(), but the Sequel docs for Sequel::SQLite::Dataset, which are here:

http://rdoc.info/github/evanfarrar/opensprints/Sequel/SQLite/Dataset

do not list that method, and the fact that you are getting an undefined method error is pretty good evidence that Sequel does not implement insert_ignore() for sqlite.

However, according to the sqlite docs here:

http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

sqlite does support INSERT OR IGNORE queries.  So, if you want to use that functionality, it looks like you'll have to use raw sql with Sequel:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'sqlite3'

DB = Sequel.sqlite('mydb1.db') 

DB.create_table! :users do
  primary_key :id
  String :name, :default => nil, :unique => true
end

#users = [{:name => 'bob'}, {:name => 'bob'}, {:name => 'mary'}]

my_insert =<<END_OF_QUERY
  INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users(name) VALUES
    ('bob'),
    ('bob'),
    ('mary')
END_OF_QUERY


data_set = DB[my_insert]
data_set.insert
```

Answer (score 0):

Your way worked, but I ended up doing something like:

```
                record = DB[table.to_sym].where(data)
                    if 1 != record.update(data)
                      DB[table.to_sym].insert(data)
                    end
                end
```

this way the record gets updated if it already exists

Answer (score 0):

The `sequel` gem has now implemented [SQLite support for `Dataset#insert_ignore`](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/pull/1121), released with version `4.30.0` on Jan 4 2016.

Upgrading to `sequel` `>= 4.30.0` should solve this issue.